# Angular - Use navigate with complex url when opening modals via routing

Tags: angular, routes, modal-dialog

I am working on an existing app which has several pages with paging/sorting and tables.
Modals are opened via routing which causes url like:
http://www.example.com/table;sort=name,desc/new

Is there any way with 
this.router.navigate() to produce search an url please?
I need to use this.router.navigate because the link to be relative to the url.
So routerLink does not work here.

Problem is that by default this.router.navigate will encode the url which causes the routing to fail.

Update:
Ok I found myself the answer.
One can do
this.router.navigate(this.router.url, {sort: 'name,desc'},'new'], { relativeTo: this.route });

It is just annoying to have to collect parameters in the base url to pass them again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the choice here depends on whether or not you want to be able to refer to the modal directly using an URL for example.

If this is required then I would recommend reforming your url to something like

```
 http://www.yoursite.com/table?sort=name,desc
```

When you want to refer them to the modal you could pass in the paramaters to the other url aswell like so:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/table/modal?sort=name,desc
```

You can solve the parameter saving in two ways if you want to refer them back to the base /table page. You can either listen for router changes and copy the parameters if the previous url was the modal link or you could change the routerLink in your html to the table page and place the current parameters there.

If referring to the modal directly is not required you are better off storing the information in a service or saving it in the component itself as the modal could just load on top of the component.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my request now that I understand better how the app works.